# SSIS :How can I set a delay time or a task for waiting a connection from a web service

Tags: ssis

I create a SSIS package using a web service task to get data from a soap web service but I often found error about a max connection pool reach.

I cannot fix a connection issue. So, I would like to know do a SSIS have a solution to set a delay time when I looping data or a solution to wait until a connection release or not?

Error:

> "Error: 0xC002F304 at Web Service Task, Web Service Task: An error
>   occurred with the following error message:
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException:
>   The Web Service threw an error during method execution. The error is:
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout
>   expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection
>   from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections
>   were in use and max pool size was reached. at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()"

[image]

Comment: Is the `max connection pool` from the database or from the web service? Maybe it would help to post the error in detail. You can delay  for 1 minute by running this in a sql task: `WAITFOR DELAY '00:01';`

Comment: Hello Nick, It is the max connection pool from the web service. I can set delay in a sql task right?PS:I already added an error on the main question.

Comment: Your best bet is to do a custom script (in C# or VB) that suspends the process while waiting for an X amount of time, and link this script component to an error flow from your Web Service, with a max execution error of N (as much tries as you like). Don't use a SQL task to delay, as you will be mantaining a pointless session with your database just to stall. http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com.es/2014/06/retry-task-on-failure.html

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say pointless. It does what is required. It's more pointless to build a web service integration in SSIS when in the end it has so much script it would be better off just totally built in powershell or C#